# execute shell with find gun at background

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

i have set of shells at the same directory ,I want to execute all shells that have result at the beginning like:

```
result.sha
result.shb
result.shc
...
```

the below script its worked find to execute all shells with matched reg, but how can I make each of them running at the background in parallel

```
find . -type f -name 'result.*' -exec sh {} \;
```

i have tried this but its not working:

```
find . -type f -name 'result.*' -exec sh {} \;&
```

Comment: Note that it's not good form to run programs as `sh scriptname`; doing so ignores that program's shebang, preventing it from being able to choose which shell to run with (if it, f/e, requires ksh or bash extensions; or is a Python or awk script or a compiled executable and not a shell script at all). `./scriptname`, by contrast, lets the OS start up the script's interpreter of choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More efficient to only start `sh` once per batch of `find` results, and let it fork off as many subprocesses as it wants.

```
find . -type f -name 'result.*' -exec sh -c 'for arg do . "$arg" & done' _ {} +
```

`. "$arg" &` forks off a copy of the already-running interpreter and runs the code in `"$arg"` inside it, avoiding paying interpreter startup costs extra times.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution runs the find program in the background rather than executing each shell script in the background. I tried myself with the find utility but could not get it to work. However, the following shell script will do what you require.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for prog in result.*
do
    sh $prog &
done
exit 0
```

or the equivalent instruction on 1 line